# Autocompletar el valor del siguiente Input según la selección de mi campo select, PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">            
                   <label for="Neconomico">Numero Económico</label>
                   <select name="Neconomico" id="Neconomico" class="form-control" style=" height:47px;">
                      <option value="">OPCIONES</option>    
                                     <?php

                                              $item = null;
                                              $valor = null;

                                         $vehiculos = ControllerVehiculos::ctrMostrarVehiculo($item, $valor);

                                               foreach ($vehiculos as $key => $value) {
                                                
                                                 echo '<option value="'.$value["id"].'">'.$value["neconomico"].'</option>';
                                                    


                                               }

                                            ?>
          
                 </select>   
                 </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                 <label for="Placas">Placas</label>
                 <input type="text" id="nuevasPlacas" name="nuevasPlacas"  class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="No. Placas" required  value="<?php echo $value["Placas"] ?>">
             </div>
```

lo unico que quiero es que segun la selección de mi select me tome el siguiente input el valor de su siguiente campo que es placas con el mismo id[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahi tenes que usar JavaScript para que uses un event listener, capturado el evento que uso el select, se genere consulta que rellene el input que quieres

Comment: Hace un rato hice un demo, que tiene un formulario que genera una pequeña cotizacion, cuando se escoge un valor del select, se genera una consulta con JS al backend que devuelve un valor y con JS lo agregas a uno de los campos del formulario mira si se entiende -> https://github.com/aumartinez/eom-demo

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar peticiones *AJAX*, agrega el valor de placas como [atributo de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos) a cada opción:

```
foreach ($vehiculos as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value=\"{$value['id']}\" data-placas\"{$value['Placas']}\">{$value['neconomico']}</option>';
}
```

Agregas una pequeña función en *Javascript* para obtener las placas desde la opción seleccionada, por su [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), y asignar el valor al campo:

```js
// Ejecutar cuando se cargue el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Obtener select y campo de placas
    let nEconomico = document.querySelector('#Neconomico');
    let placas = document.querySelector('#nuevasPlacas');
    // Escuchar cuando cambie valor del select
    nEconomico.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        // Obtener opción seleccionada
        let opt = nEconomico.options[nEconomico.selectedIndex];
        // Establecer valor del input nuevasPlacas
        // Si opt tiene valor de placas, asignarlo, de lo contrario, queda vacío
        placas.value = (opt.dataset.placas) ? opt.dataset.placas : '';
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">            
                   <label for="Neconomico">Numero Económico</label>
                   <select name="Neconomico" id="Neconomico" class="form-control" style=" height:47px;">
                      <option value="">OPCIONES</option>
                      <option value="1" data-placas="Placas1">N. Económico 1</option>
                      <option value="2" data-placas="Placas2">N. Económico 2</option>
                      <option value="3" data-placas="Placas3">N. Económico 3</option>
                      <option value="4" data-placas="Placas4">N. Económico 4</option>
                 </select>   
                 </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                 <label for="Placas">Placas</label>
                 <input type="text" id="nuevasPlacas" name="nuevasPlacas"  class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="No. Placas" required  value="">
             </div>
```